# Does AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne block the CLR thread? Or does it create an I/O completion port?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, iasyncresult

I have that question, does `AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne` block the CLR thread? or does it create an I/O completion port?

For example, when I run my application I launch a task 'A' that initializes some data, when new requests arrives, I want them to wait till 'A' has finished, so I can do a `IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne`, but... does it block the calling thread till 'A' ends or does it create a I/O completion port that will be also notified when 'A' finish.

If not, is there a way to do that?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it blocks the thread, but like any other `WaitHandle`, it blocks in the OS kernel so it doesn't take any cpu time.

If you don't want to block your thread, but do want a "callback", you can use the thread pool:

```
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject( waitHandle, callback, ...
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9f75h7a.aspx : "The wait operation is performed by a thread from the thread pool", so there is no point in this since it will block a threadpool thread anyway, that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: The thread pool has special threads that it uses for waiting. Each of these can wait for up to 63 objects at a time, so there is some advantage.

Comment: That is interesting, where could I find more information about that?

Comment: Found it! "Concurrent Programming on Windows" by Joe Duffy: chapter 7 "Thread Pools", section "CLR Thread Pool", subsection "Registered Waits", page 375.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Concurrent-Programming-Windows-Joe-Duffy/dp/032143482X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1323778992&sr=8-1 Can I assume that only the chapters 8 and 9 are about the .NET framework?

Comment: That's the one. It covers native and managed code throughout. It's the "bible" - I strongly suggest everyone reads it! It's also on Safari Books, if you have a subscription.